# Scale a particle system in SceneKit

Tags: swift, scenekit, particle-system, scnnode

I'm doing a game with SceneKit for which the size of the whole game can change, i.e. the size of the reference node (GameRootNode) to which all nodes are linked can change, then all nodes size change accordingly when it happens.

When it comes to particle system, it is getting tricky. So far I had to do a particle system for each extreme of the size range the game can have, and play with the properties of the particle system to adjust the effect. The result is not good.

So I have tried to scale the particle system with 2 approaches :

- attach the `BulletNode` to the `GameRootNode`, attach the particle system to the `BulletNode` then scale the `GameRootNode` (as described below)
- scale the `GameRootNode`, create the `BulletNode`, attach the particle system to the `BulletNode` then scale the `BulletNode` to the same scale than the `GameRootNode`

In both cases, the particle system stays with its original size (i.e. the one defined in the SceneKit editor)

Is there a way to scale particle system?

```
GameRootNode = SCNNode()
let Sequence = SCNAction.sequence([SCNAction.scale(to: VCOfScene.VCPlayAR.ScalingFactor, duration: 0), 
                                   SCNAction.move(to: SCNVector3.init(-Float(kNbColonnesLevel) / 2 * Float(VCOfScene.VCPlayAR.ScalingFactor), 
                                   0, 
                                  -Float(kNbLignesLevel) / 2 * Float(VCOfScene.VCPlayAR.ScalingFactor)), 
                                   duration: 0)])
GameRootNode.runAction(Sequence)

BulletNode = SCNNode(geometry: Level3D.Bullet.geometry)
BulletNode.position = Position.PositionToVector()
BulletNode.name = ProjectileImageName + String(ProjectileID)

let BulletShape = SCNParticleSystem(named: "Fireball.scnp", inDirectory: nil)!
BulletShape.emittingDirection = DirectionBullet
BulletShape.particleColor = Character.Color

BulletNode.addParticleSystem(BulletShape)
GameRootNode.addChildNode(BulletNode)
GameRootNode.runAction(Sequence)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to scale a particle system: Shapes' `Width`,`Height`,`Length` as well as particle system's `X`,`Y`,`Z` Scale.

Here's an example how you can scale your particle system using SCNAction:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/myScene.scn")!

    //.......................................................

    let particleSystem = SCNParticleSystem()
    particleSystem.emitterShape = SCNBox(width: 1,
                                        height: 1,
                                        length: 1,
                                 chamferRadius: 0)

    particleSystem.birthRate = 50
    particleSystem.particleSize = 0.05
    particleSystem.stretchFactor = 2
    particleSystem.particleLifeSpan = 3
    particleSystem.particleVelocity = 10

    let psNode = SCNNode()
    psNode.addParticleSystem(particleSystem)
    psNode.scale = SCNVector3(1, 1, 1)

    let action = SCNAction.sequence([SCNAction.scale(by: 5, duration: 10)])
    psNode.runAction(action)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(psNode)
}
```

When you scale up a particle system you should increase `Birth rate` property accordingly. For instance, your `scale` was `(x:1, y:1, z:1)` and `Birth rate = 50`. And you decided to increase a `scale` to `(x:5, y:5, z:5)`.

> In order to retain the same particles' density you have to increase `Birth rate` property (by 125 times, for example, if your scale factor is 5).

Comment: Thanks but it seems to be close to what I've tried. The scaling action is done on the node but not on the particle system. You need as you mentioned to change the parameters of the particle system in order to have the same behavior, not only birth rate but also some others.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to change some other parameters. Could you tell me what parameters precisely?

Comment: Well, you have to play with almost all parameters to conserve the same effect when the scale is changing, especially with complex and multiple particle systems attached to one node. In fact, scaling the node to which the particle system(s) is(are) attached doesn't do anything. I guess that scaling a particle system is not possible.